# How can I check a variable (modifiable) string in Unix?

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

I am using Unix on a Bash Shell and wish to verify that it is of the following form:

```
[0-9*][,[0-9*]*]
```

So, the following strings would all be valid:

- 141,325,562
- 65
- 659,948,8465,9853,2659,156,884,351,0,451,01,10

My Unix is rather basic so all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should it match on `,1`, `1,,2`, `1,` or the empty string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match on the content of a shell variable in `bash`, `zsh` or `ksh93`:

```
re='^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$'
[[ $string =~ $re ]] && echo matches
```

POSIXly:

```
case $string in
  ("" | *[!,0-9]* | ,* | *, | *,,*) ;;
  (*) echo matches;;
esac
```

Bournely:

```
expr " $string" : ' [0-9]\{1,\}\(,[0-9]\{1,\}\)*$' > /dev/null &&
  echo matches
```

To match on lines of input:

```
grep -xE '[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*'
```

We use `+` (or the BRE equivalent `\{1,\}`) to match **1** or more digits. `*` would match **0** or more.

Comment: I can understand that one and it is nice and Unix (I get lost in Perl and so on). Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The regex you want is probably this one:

```
[0-9]*[,[0-9]+]*
```

Additionally, you can check regex on-the-fly with this tool: https://regex101.com/

Comment: doesn't work for me. and I am not sure regexp can match OP need.

Comment: `[,[0-9]` matches a single character that either `,`, `[` or a digit.

Comment: Same-o here, use parenthesis `(...)` to group in `grep -E` and Perl regexes, not brackets.